# WPF DataGrid issue between Windows 7 and Windows XP when ItemsSource is Dictionary.Value Collection

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

I have

```
Dictionary<int, MyType> services = new Dictionary<int, MyType>();
```

which then I fill appropriately and then try to bind to WPF DataGrid in two different ways:

```
    /* 1 */ Grid_RunDates.ItemsSource = services.Values.ToList<MyType>();
    /* ... */
    /* 2 */ Grid_RunDates.ItemsSource = services.Values;
```

I am compiling this on Windows 7 and 8.1 in VS 2013 for .NET 4.0 Client Profile (while the installed version is 4.5.2) and then go to the Windows XP SP3 test environment with .NET 4.0 Client Profile.

/1/ works fine on Windows 7/8.1 but not on Windows XP. In the latter OS I get appropriate number of rows in DataGrid, but they are narrow, empty, and no columns are generated.
/2/ works fine in both.

There is absolutely no difference between /1/ and /2/ but the OS the fact that
/1/ uses List while /2/ uses Dictionary.ValueCollection

If somebody wanted to know MyType looks like this

```
public class MyType
{
 public int Prop0 { get; set; }
 public string Prop1 { get; set; }
 public string Prop2 { get; set; }
 public bool Prop3 { get; set; }
 public DateTime Prop4 { get; set; }
}
```

The question is: why? Why does Windows XP fail to generate the view with Dictionary.ValueCollection?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: ToList is an extension method and might have different behavior based on the implementation. as you are able to see the rows, check if auto generate columns is enabled or not.

Comment: Yes, I thought about it and set explictly AutoGenerateColumns to true, but to  no avail.

Comment: as a suggestion try to make MyType public and see if that helps.

Comment: It is public, I just didn't type it above, as I didn't think it should matter.

Comment: That is probably not a difference between XP and 7, but a difference between .NET 4 and .NET 4.5; between these versions, the logic for auto-generating the column names could have changed. (Remember that .NET 4 shipped the first version of the `DataGrid`). However, unless someone disassembles (or finds the reference source for .NET 4.0 lying around, something that I could not do) the .NET 4.0 version of `PresentationFramework.dll`, it is just a guess.